# i have 18126 rows × 63 columns but when i do { data.columns } it shows only 49

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, exploratory-data-analysis

There are 63 columns but it shows only 49 columns:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Data is you data frame?

Comment: yes   ie data  =  pd.read_csv("/kaggle/input/2021-new-coder-survey/2021 New Coder Survey.csv" )

Comment: Picture a very poor format to exchange textual data. Never post picture for logs, code, data, error copy paste instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you have 63 columns. You have multiple times 39 (x7) and 45 (x8)

Try:

```
>>> len(df.columns)
```

Remove the prefix number of the question to be not confused:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('^\d+\.\s+', '')
```

Some questions are the same:

```
'39. How much debt does your household have? [Car loans]',
'39. How much debt does your household have? [Credit Cards]',
'39. How much debt does your household have? [Medical Loans]',
'39. How much debt does your household have? [Mortgages]',
'39. How much debt does your household have? [Payday Loans]',
'39. How much debt does your household have? [Student Loans]',
'39. How much debt does your household have? [Other]',
```

```
'45. Please tell us how satisfied you are with each of these following aspects of your present job [Earnings]',
'45. Please tell us how satisfied you are with each of these following aspects of your present job [Benefits]',
'45. Please tell us how satisfied you are with each of these following aspects of your present job [Job security]',
'45. Please tell us how satisfied you are with each of these following aspects of your present job [Work-life balance]',
'45. Please tell us how satisfied you are with each of these following aspects of your present job [Professional growth or leadership opportunities]',
'45. Please tell us how satisfied you are with each of these following aspects of your present job [Workplace/company culture]',
'45. Please tell us how satisfied you are with each of these following aspects of your present job [Diverse and inclusive work environment]',
'45. Please tell us how satisfied you are with each of these following aspects of your present job [Weekly workload]',
```

Comment: len(data.columns) = 63

Answer (score 1):

You can try different methods to get the number of rows and columns of the dataframe in pandas :

```
len(df)
len(df. index)
df. shape
df. count()
df. size.
```

Comment: i want to extract the name of all 63 columns but showing me just 49 names of colums

Comment: With the help of the Python list() function, you can obtain the column names from a Pandas DataFrame. Once you have the data, you can print it using the print() statement. This statement's df.